# How can I simplify this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, css

I have three divs which are stacked with css on top of each other. The middle one should be a draggable separator, such that the top div and its content is above and the other div is below. And each has its own scrollbar. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4j3V/1/)

It works however if find my js code not very nice because it set the heights of the three divs separately:

The html:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    <div id="dragger"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The css code

```css
 #wrapper {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
     position: relative;
 }
 #content {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 25%;
     width:100%;
     height: 75%;
     overflow:scroll;
     overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 #dragger {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 25%;
     width:100%;
     cursor: ns-resize;
     height: 5px;
 }
 #footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;

     width:100%;
     height: 25%;
     overflow:scroll;
     overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

The js code:

```js
   ...
   $('#footer').css({
        "height": bodySize - e.pageY
    });
    $('#content').css({
        "bottom": bodySize - e.pageY,
            "height": e.pageY
    });
    $('#dragger').css({
        "bottom": bodySize - e.pageY
    });
    ...
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same behavior, I thought of some way to make the footer and content div height depending on the position of dragger in css. But I do not know how. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/d4j3V/4/

You are making the same call three times. Instead of doing that, just calculate it at the beginning:

```
var height = bodySize - e.pageY;
```

Then drop that variable every place you did the calculation:

```
$('#footer').css({
    "height": height
});
$('#content').css({
    "bottom": height,
     height": e.pageY
});
$('#dragger').css({
    "bottom": height
});
```

Also, instead of calling `$(document.body)` three different times, just chain the various `on` calls together.

```
$(document.body).on("mousemove", function (e) {
    ....
}).on("mousedown", "#dragger", function (e) {
    ....
}).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my aim is that I only need to change the position of one div and the others adapt accoridingly.

Comment: I don't see how you can make that happen any other way than what you have already done. HTML elements are not generally "smart" enough to know what their siblings are doing, especially when it comes to height.

Comment: Well, I take that back. You could move the containing element to a table with two one-cell rows. You could then make some JS magic happen to drag and resize those two cells. There are a few plugins that could make it happen for you.